# In Flutter, how can a child widget prevent the scrolling of its scrollable parent?

Tags: flutter, gesture

I have a scrollable widget, say a ListView, which contains some special widget.

How can I prevent the scrollable to scroll when the user tries to scroll by starting to scroll on top of that widget?

In other words, I want that widget to be like a "hole" that prevents the scrollable to sense gestures there.

Comment: Can that child be a parent of the scroll instead? That's contrary to how the widget system works, where descendants cannot alter the behavior of their parents.

Comment: @RémiRousselet No, if the child is scrolling inside of the scrollable, how could it be the parent? Can't the child somehow "capture" the gesture? I don't know much about the gesture arena and related classes...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap the widget with `GestureDetector` and implement empty gesture functions in it.

```
GestureDetector(
   onVerticalDragUpdate: (_) {},
   child: YourWidget
),
```

Comment: Trivial, now that I know.

Comment: This prevents the child from receiving the gesture also.

Answer (score 1):

If your child is `WebView`, `GoogleMap` or similar, you can make it to use `EagerGestureRecognizer`:

```dart
WebView(
  ...
  gestureRecognizers: {
    Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
      () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
    ),
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not satisfying because it prevents the child from receiving gestures (at least on native platforms).

Only acceptable solution I found -- in my case with a PageView -- is to disable the scroll gestures when the page with the gesturedetector child displays.

If anyone has a cleaner solution, please let us know.